# Non-circularity of a part-whole relation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The naive definition of a set as a collection of objects requires an explanation on how the objects related to the collection.

Mereology suggests to view the part-whole relation based on the three properties:

- Reflexivity: can a collection contain itself?
- Symmetry: can two collections belong to each other?
- Transitivity: if an object $x$ belongs to a collection $y$, and collection $y$ belongs to a collection $z$, is $x$ an element of $z$?

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/

From this point of view part-whole relations are not much different from order relations.

If we see an order as a transitive non-symmetric relation, then any order is a part-whole relation.
And vice versa, mereology itself can be viewed as partial order theory.

But here is a problem.
A cyclic order is an order since it is transitive and asymmetric.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order

From another hand when we think of a part-whole relation we do not expect circularity.
I would suggest “non-circularity” is essential for the part-whole concept.

In ZFC non-circularity follows from the axiom of regularity, but the axiom also forbids “ungrounded” sets.

I am trying to formulate the property of non-circularity explicitly.

We can say that a chain $a_1Ra_2Ra_3 ... Ra_n$, $n > 1$, of a relation $R$ is a cycle if $a_1 = a_n$.
Clearly, a relation is non-circular if it does not have cycles.

This way we could classify a part-whole relation as non-symmetric and non-circular.

Similar to the definitions of *a-* and *anti-* symmetry we could define the non-circular properties:

- A-circularity: $a_1 \ne a_n$ in any chain $a_1Ra_2Ra_3 ... Ra_n$, $n > 1$;
- Anti-circularity: if $a_1 = a_n$ in a chain $a_1Ra_2Ra_3 ... Ra_n$, $n > 1$, then $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = ... = a_n$.

It is easy to show that a-circularity implies irreflexivity and asymmetry:

- If $xRx$, then $a_1 = a_2$ in the chain $a_1Ra_2$, where $a_1$ = $a_2 = x$, contradiction;
- If $xRy$ and $yRx$, then $a_1 = a_3$ in the chain $a_1Ra_2Ra_3$, where $a_1$ = $a_3 = x$, and $a_2 = y$, contradiction;

Using the properties, we could give an alternative classification of part-whole relations:

- Membership $\in$: a non-transitive a-circular part-whole relation;
- Proper inclusion $\subset$: a transitive a-circular part-whole relation;
- Inclusion $\subseteq$: $x \subseteq y \iff x \subset y \lor x = y$ (that assumes anti-circularity).

Are the definitions logically correct?
Are there more accurate definitions of non-circular relations?
Are there studies on non-circularity as a principle of part-whole relations?

Comment: Not very clear... Are you assuming as primitive (undefined) the concept of (binary) relation, state some basic properties (a-circular) and with them *define* membership and (proper) inclusion?

Comment: If so, IMO the relation "... is son of..." is a-circular, but it is not (set) membership. The relation "... is a descendant of..." is transitive an acircular, but it is not (set) inclusion.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't think it is possible to clearly separate all order relations from part-whole relations. One could say "my son is my part", or "my family is my part". I am only trying to add one more "coordinate" to the picture. My concern is if it is correctly formulated and can be used together with the reflexivity-symmetry-transitivity properties in application to set theory. I don't mind if it is applied outside of set theory as well.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I added the part-whole notion into the definitions. Does it look better this way?

Comment: I just saw this Lemma in Birkoff's "Lattice Theory": $x_1\leqq x_2 \leqq ... \leqq x_n \leqq x_1$ then $x_1 =x_2 =...=x_n$. (anti-circularity).